# MySQL remote access, telnet and ping not working across servers with the same top-level domain

Tags: php, mysql, database, linux, telnet

I have built an app (in PHP) to loop through a database list that I have configured and individually connect to those remote databases (standard MySQL on port 3306) and fetch relevant data for my app from those DBs.

However, some of those connections simply "froze" eventually delivering a can't connect to MySQL on remote 'x.x.x.x' etc.

Upon further investigation I could see that iptables was accepting input and output for port 3306 and I could connect in the same way from some other servers whereas my app server could not. I have checked the configuration of mysql for remote access from all hosts etc. --skip-netwokring is commented out so should be be able to connect remotely, --skip-name-resolve is also in there to avoid trying to resolve the ip into a DNS name and in fact I can connect from several other servers but not the app server (as I have just said)

So, here is my theory and what I need help with. Let's say, the following:

**App server**: (centOs) connects to all remote databases and fetches data for app. RDNS is **x1.somedomain.com**

**Database 1**: (centOs) holds data. RDNS is **x2.somedomain.com**

**Database 2**: (Debian) holds data. RDNS is **someotherdomain.com**

The app server has issues connecting to database 1. As a debugging method I then tried to telnet 3306 and ping from the app server to db 1 with no response. If I do the same from db 2 to db 1 it works. If I do the reverse and telnet and ping from db 1 to the app server it doesn't work still but if I telnet and ping from db 1 to db 2 then it works just fine (and visa versa).

I had also tried to do the same debugging methods from other linux Os from a virtual box and it worked fine. Therefore, this suggests only one thing left to me which is that the app server doesn't even send the request because somehow it looks at the tld and "thinks" it is not a remote connection and creates some kinda of loopback error or the receiving server checks the IP of the requesting server and rejects it because as it realizes it is a remote request but the tld is the same as the localhost so rejects.

I have been struggling with this all weekend and can't find the answer on the system logs so I hope somebody can give me some insight to resolving this and point out what I need to do to resolve it and getting Database 1 to respond with data for the app server.

Many thanks.

**EDIT:**

- The servers do not use any security apart from iptables, so not so sure about how lockout would occur.

App server iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/x -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/x -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
*mangle
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed
*nat
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed
```

DB1 iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [57850:6391695]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4275:348954]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4275:348954]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 20 12:56:40 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [299933:34182855]
:INPUT ACCEPT [299486:34132134]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [326963:298292395]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [326963:298292395]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 20 12:56:40 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [65322:6355987]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 20 12:56:40 2013
```

**EDIT 2**:

Solution found. now resolved. See accepted answer.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you using IPs in all your connections or are you using hostnames (someotherdomain.com, x2.somedomain.com etc)?
Also - is it possible you've locked yourself out due to security SW on the server (ConfigServer has done this to me a few times)

Comment: I am using IPs in all connections and thought that name resolving (on mysql config) was the issue at first hence why I am using IPs only and the setting --skip-name-resolve now but still no luck. Could you however, explain security SW to me please? thanks

Comment: Are you able to ping,telnet,connect from your app server to db2 or any other server in your network, if cannot then something is wrong with app server,check out iptables rules and try to flush them,make sure you don't have a router or firewall or any Intrusion Detection-Prevention to the app server preventing outgoing and incoming connections.

Comment: Hi linux_fanatic, I am able to ping/telnet and connect from app server to db2, just not db1. Db2 is able to do the same to both so, no particular obvious connection problem here as I have no specific iptables rules on particular ips, just whether a port is open or not. I do not have external hardware in place that 'listens' before the server and checks for intrusion detection of sorts so I don't think that is the case either. Would you like me to paste the iptables rules on here so you can have a look? just in case. thanks

Comment: The fact that db1 won't accept ANY connections (beit ping, telnet, or myssql, all of which are on diff ports) from your app server seems to indicate some type of lockout. If you have CPANEL, check CPHulk, see if the ip or host is in the blacklist. If you have lfd/Configserver ('software firewall/security suite'), it could do this type of block BUT then I'd expect to see something in iptables (it uses iptables as the means to prevent/allow access).

Comment: No, db1 does accept some connections. For example it accepts from db2 all connections I am trying but not all connections from app server but DOES allow from app server telnet on port 22 for example (ssh). Ok - thanks. Will try a few other things in line with what you are saying and hopefully resolve it otherwise I guess back to the drawing board. Thanks. Will paste my iptables in moment too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. It turns out that everything was set-up correctly from the very beginning and what I was getting was very strange behavior due to it looking like it should work hence, why i needed all your help.

However, I have now finally figured it out. It turns out that the hosting provider did actually put certain ports behind a firewall **and did not make this clear to me in any way** because this firewall is only particularly active between local servers under the same hosting provider. Therefore,  (because db1 and the app server) are with the same hosting provider they could not connect to each other but db2 could (including pinging and telnet) because that server is under a different hosting provider. Apparently, the hosting providing wants an extra £10 per server per month to open a private LAN between app server and db1 server :/

Solution; I'm moving the app server to a different host (and always double check if there is no firewall on the LAN as my confusion was that there was no firewall on the WAN but there was on the LAN).

Thanks for all the help.